# How to put array to obj in php?

Tags: php

I have an json obj:

```
$response["data"][] = array("ID" => $comment["ID"]);
```

I put to new obj like this:

```
array_push($response["username"],"abc");
```

and it return like this:

```
{"data":[{"ID":"2106"}],"username":"123"}
```

but I want to like this:

```
 {"data":[{"ID":"2106","username":"123"}]}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this:

```
{"data":[{"ID":"2106", "username":"123"}]
```

BTW you need

```
array_push($response["data]["username"],"abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
$response["data"][] = array("ID" => $comment["ID"], 'username' => '123');
```

Please note that you can always simplify your code to make it more readable by creating variables.

```
$row = array(
    'ID' => $comment['ID'], 
    'username' => '123'
);
$response['data'][] = $row;
```